# In NetLogo how do you get rid of the World View

Tags: netlogo

The title says it all. I'm building an application with switches, sliders, and plots but no 2-dimensional display.  Is there a way to delete the World display? Of course I can shrink it down, and I can set all the turtles to `hidden?`, but I can't find a way to get rid of it entirely. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nicolas says, there is no official way to do this.

The workaround I would suggest is to set max-pxcor to 0, reducing the view's height to a minimum, then covering it with an opaque "note".

Click "Add", then select "Note", click in the Interface tab to create the note, then uncheck the "Transparent background" checkbox. Then drag and resize the note as needed.

Comment: Thanks. (Extra characters to allow me to add this note.)

Answer (score 1):

There is *officially* no way to make the view disappear in NetLogo.

But (and I probably shouldn't be telling you this) there is [a bug](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/326) in NetLogo that you could take advantage of. If you run:

```
set-patch-size -1
```

...the view disappears!

If you save and re-load your model, however, it reappears. (This is because NetLogo makes sure that the view is some minimum size when loading a model.) You can get around that by using a [`startup`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/startup.html) procedure:

```
to startup
  set-patch-size -1
end
```

But, be warned: you probably shouldn't do that. This is very much a hack. The bug will probably be fixed eventually, so you can't expect this to keep working. And it may very well cause other, unforeseeable problems.

---

The wisest thing to do is probably be to just move the view far out of the way, so that the user has to scroll a long way to see it. That would make the view "hidden" for most intents and purposes and wouldn't cause any trouble.

Comment: Thanks. (Extra characters to allow me to add this note.)